# App Service Certificate Denied but Domain verification passed?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

Based on the documentation I've read, the "Denied" status should only happen if the domain fails to verify.
[image]

[image]

[image: Verification shown successful]

[image: Passed]

But clearly the verification passed so I'm not sure what else to do.
Attempting to follow the sub-steps under the Assign step just leads to errors related to
the cert being in the "Denied" state still.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was not domain verification as stated in the other answer here and in the documentation, but was a misconfigured CAA record on the DNS.

For wildcard certs you need to have an

```
0 issuewild godaddy.com
```

record on the root domain - not on a star (*) domain.